# How to Query OR condition in Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to run OR condition to find users with either Microsoft 365 E5 or Office 365 E3 license assigned but its not working. Can someone please help to correct it ?

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=assignedLicenses/any(x:x/skuId eq '18181a46-0d4e-45cd-891e-60aabd171b4e' or x/skuId eq '06ebc4ee-1bb5-47dd-8120-11324bc54e06')
```

Answer (score 1):

The property `assignedLicenses` on [user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) resource supports only `eq` parameter. Do not use quotes around the value.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=assignedLicenses/any(x:x/skuId eq 18181a46-0d4e-45cd-891e-60aabd171b4e)
```